# Unity Player/Camera in Update?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing a Jump and Run Game in Unity. I have a problem with th three methods update, late update and fixed update. I know what each of these does. As my Player is moved with physics (velocity), i put him in fixed update. And my Camera is in Update. But then my Player stutters

So i put my Camera in fixedUpdate. My Player runs smooth now but my Platforms stutter. Can sb tell me in which of the three methods i have to put my camera and where my player (btw the camera relies on player position) or what to do in general?

Dan

The following are my three scripts

Player Movement Script

```
//Jump
public float jumpForce;
private bool isGrounded;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
[SerializeField] private UnityEngine.Transform groundCheck;
[SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;
[SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer sb;

//Movement
public float speed;
bool moveRightPressed = false;
bool moveLeftPressed = false;
bool jumpPressed = false;
private Vector2 defaultVector = new Vector2(0, 0);
private float horizontalMove = 0;

//Animation
private Animator anim;

private void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    sb = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

//Check for Buttons
public void PointerDownMoveRight()
{
    moveRightPressed = true;
}

public void PointerUpMoveRight()
{
    moveRightPressed = false;
}

public void PointerDownMoveLeft()
{
    moveLeftPressed = true;
}

public void PointerUpMoveLeft()
{
    moveLeftPressed = false;
}

public void PointerDownJump()
{
    jumpPressed = true;
}

public void PointerUpJump()
{
    jumpPressed = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    if (isGrounded)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
    }

    if (moveLeftPressed)
    {
        horizontalMove = -speed;
        anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        if (!sb.flipX)
        {
            sb.flipX = true;
        }
    }
    else if (moveRightPressed)
    {
        horizontalMove = speed;
        anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        if (sb.flipX)
        {
            sb.flipX = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        horizontalMove = 0;
        anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        if (sb.flipX)
        {
            sb.flipX = false;
        }
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalMove, rb.velocity.y);
    if (jumpPressed)
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
            anim.SetTrigger("takeOf");
        }
    }
}
```

Camera Movement Script

```
public Transform target; //Player
public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;  
public Vector3 offset;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 desiredPosition = new Vector3(target.position.x + offset.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
    transform.position = smoothedPosition;
}
```

Parallax Background Script

```
private float length, startpos;
public GameObject cam;
public float parallaxEffect;

private void Start()
{
    startpos = transform.position.x;
    length = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.x;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    float dist = (cam.transform.position.x * parallaxEffect);
    transform.position = new Vector3(startpos + dist, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

[image: Game hierarchy]

btw I use UI Buttons for the movement

Comment: maybe try put your Camera update method in `LateUpdate`. https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-follow-the-player-with-a-camera-in-unity-with-or-without-cinemachine/

Comment: Can you please share your code (all update methods) and a screenshot of your scene hierarchy?

Comment: As @WillardPeng suggests I would also go with `LateUpdate` for any camera movement reacting to player input. However, if there is a circular dependency between player position and camera position ... then something doesn't sound right. Please share your code

Comment: @derHugo i edited my post and shared the code. Hope it is helpful!

Comment: @PavlosMavris i edited my post and shared the code. Hope it is helpful!

Comment: why is your background a child of the camera and at the same time it makes its position depending on the camera position?

Comment: I got the background from this tutorial: https://youtu.be/zit45k6CUMk

Comment: @derHugo It moves with the camera but * parallax effect times faster - this way i think the parallax is created

Comment: @DanxAG it makes no sense though to nest this under the camera again .. currently ther are two things moving it: The camera and its own script ... it should probably just not be a child of the camera or use the `localPosition` so it only applies an offset within the camera's local space

Comment: @derHugo I changed it, as you said it makes no sense - now it's clear to me. But the game is still stuttering and i don't know why

Comment: So in general I think the camera and parallax should be done in `LateUpdate` not in `FixedUpdate` and then the camera interpolation be based on `Time.deltaTime` do not be frame rate dependent

Comment: @derHugo so transform.position = smoothedPosition * Time.deltaTime ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the problem: My phone was set to 120 fps (which I didn't know, so I expected it to be 60). However setting the fps of my phone to 60fps or building the game for 120fps solves the issue.